# Define server location in html jquery project

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, security, web-config

I'm developing web system using html, jquery and node js server. Currently i'm calling ajax like below.

```
          $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: serverLocation + "/api/dashboard/createUser",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(reqJson),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    showAlertBox(response.message, response.status);
                },
                error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Err');
                    showAlertBox("Somthing went wrong", false);
                }
            });
```

you can see I used ***serverLocation*** variable in url attribute. Honestly I define "serverLocation" in above of the js file as a constant and I did it in every js files. (I know it is not a good programming practice).

```
const serverLocation = "http://127.0.0.1:9173";
```

So when we going to deploy in production server, how to define this serverlocation in one place and use it in all js files?

The other question is, expose this kind of server information in client side will hit to security. In that case how to avoid it?

Comment: call it relatively with `url: '/api/dashboard/createUser'`. Remove the `serverLocation `

Comment: you can define it in some class (consts class) and import that class in your code or use a uniq string that will be replaced during build by a  task (gulp, bower and such)
as for security, you can hide your real sever location behind a CDN, but every url www.something.com translated to ip address, and for the whole internet to work it should be in plan sight

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need of this serverlocation kind of variable which defines the domain name or amything
You just need to put the url as `/api/dashboard/createUser` it will dynamically get the domain name or the ip and will search for the route `/api/dashboard/createUser` according to http method.
If you want to go to the link which is adding to present url that is 
If your present url `http://www.example.com/present/abc`
And you want the action to be in `http://www.example.com/present/abc/actionpage`
Then use 
`<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>` in place of severlocation
Or if again you really want the hostname then use
`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` in place of serverlocation

Comment: I'm using 2 servers for web project (Html + Jquery) and the node js server.

Comment: This `$_ SERVER[]` will take care of that

Comment: I'm using node js and are you sure that I can use above code?

Comment: Its a php code use it in the html file with php tags ....dont use in the node.js server js file

Answer (score 0):

First:

If your client(JS, HTML, and CSS) code and server code both lies in same domain you don't need to give the exact location of the server. If it is not the case then you are expected to give the full path of the server to make ajax call.

Second:
Even if you are managed to hide server link, one can get the links from browser dev tools, Don't worry about URL stored in JS. Servers are meant to handle security.

Comment: yes.. that is my question. web location and server endpoint locations are 2 servers. In that case, we must have to define the end point, isn't it?